# How to open home page of settings ios8

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I want go to setting page through my app. I am using following code but it takes me to apps setting, but want to go Home page of settings like Facebook or Twitter.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
                             URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```